# Why is this Python script running faster in the CPU than in the GPU?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, gpu, self-organizing-maps

I'm using Python's library `somoclu` to train a self-organising map using Python. The library allows users to perform the training either on the CPU (Intel Core i7-8700) or on the GPU (GeForce GTX 1080 Ti).

I noticed that the CPU was running the script faster than the GPU did, so I ran a sweep varying the number of datapoints and the size of the map, to see if at some point the GPU outperformed the CPU. This was the script:

```
import numpy as np
import somoclu
import time

m = 3 # Number of dimensions
points = [5000, 30000, 80000, 150000, 300000] # Number of datapoints
iterMax = 200 # Max number of iterations
mapSize = [4, 32, 64, 128] # Dimensions of SOM
np.random.seed(0)
#%% SOM
for n in points:
    for size in mapSize:
        y = np.random.rand(n,m) # Input data
        # With CPU
        t = time.clock() # Start time
        som = somoclu.Somoclu(size,
                              size,
                              compactsupport = False,
                              kerneltype = 0)
        som.train(y.astype(np.float32), epochs = iterMax)
        elapsedTime = time.clock() - t
        # With GPU
        t = time.clock() # Start time
        som = somoclu.Somoclu(size,
                              size,
                              compactsupport = False,
                              kerneltype = 1)
        som.train(y.astype(np.float32), epochs = iterMax)
        elapsedTime = time.clock() - t
```

I saved the times in a CSV, and this is what I got:

```
CPU                 GPU
2.7632589999999997  5.935387999999999
60.340638           82.796062
228.292085          305.75625900000006
861.3243            1141.331934
11.692982999999913  24.568256999999903
330.17140100000006  443.82112400000005
1354.677431         1749.3110039999992
5559.308704         6990.034151000002
29.3726179999976    47.36881999999969
913.3250950000001   1163.5942189999987
3703.653313999999   4615.292857
14868.418703000003  18635.051464000004
37.40133600000263   68.64375999999902
1699.020611         2141.047305
6925.692426000009   8645.564134
27887.844171999997  illegal memory access was encountered
```

As you can see, the CPU outperforms the GPU in every single case (on top of it, the GPU version crashed when running the script with 150000 datapoints and a 64x64 map). How is this possible? What is the advantage on using the GPU to train the SOM then?

EDIT:

I tried the same library in R, and in this language the GPU outperforms the CPU. So apparently is just a Python issue, but I'm no expert in programming to figure out what is happening. I believe the kernel running is the same, so it's just the interface that changes. Let's see if this helps somebody to find why in Python the CPU is going faster than the GPU.

Comment: what is the level of parallelism involved in your script?

Comment: @abc I'm not sure I can answer that question. I'm just using the mentioned library, my particular script is as simple as shown. I believe parallelism is involved inside somoclu's functions and users have no control over it.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant here, but `time.clock` is a bad way to benchmark code. If you can use `timeit`, use it; if you can't, you have to do most of what it does (including using the right clock, which is rarely `clock`, disabling GC, etc.) yourself.

Comment: Meanwhile, I know nothing about this library, but is `iterMax=200` a reasonable value, or a really tiny one, or…?

Comment: @abarnert That's a useful tip, thanks. However, I don't know why you say using time.clock is a bad idea. Why is it so? Regarding the number of iterations, I don't think it has influence on the performance. Each iteration of the SOM relies on the previous ones, so the problem is not parallelizable from that point of view. I believe that parallelism here is useful for large maps and large datasets (i.e., I believe the number of iterations is not important to compare CPU vs. GPU).

Comment: @Tendero Read [the docs for `time.clock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock). On Unix, it counts processor time rather than wall-clock time. And what counts as "processor time" is different on different Unixes. Its precision is not guaranteed to be the highest available, or even guaranteed to be better than 1 second.

Comment: @abarnert Alright, I will check it out! Nevertheless, here precision is not that critical I think, as differences between CPU and GPU times to run the script are pretty large.

Comment: The reason I asked about the number of iterations is that with large data sets, copying the data from main memory to graphics memory and back can be slow. If you do a ton of work on that data, the parallel speedup usually more than makes up for it, but if you don't, you could be adding more overhead than benefit. Larger data _might_ affect that, if the overhead is mostly linear but the speedup is super-linear—but if they're both linear, it won't make a difference.

Comment: That's why I said "I don't think this is relevant here". When people post questions asking why one function took 117ns and the other took 141ns and they're using `clock` to time a single iteration, the answer is usually just "don't use `clock`", but when you're talking about a loop over 3+ seconds of work, it's usually not. But still, better to do it right than to do it wrong and assume it's probably fine.

Comment: My opinion is that the number of iterations should depend on the map size. The convergence will be faster for small maps. As an aside, it seems that the `illegal memory access was encountered` error occurred for 128x128 maps, not 64x64 maps.

Answer (score 1):

According to Figure 5 in [this paper on somoclu](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236635216_Somoclu_An_Efficient_Parallel_Library_for_Self-Organizing_Maps), the GPU was faster. However, the paper did not show extensive benchmarking. I can only suggest that for your machine, the CPU is more capable. But you could study the paper to run a more similar test for comparison. [image]

> To ensure replicability of the results, we benchmarked with publicly
>   available cluster GPUinstances provided by Amazon Web Services.  The
>   instance type was cg1.4xlarge
>   (https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), equipped with 22 GiB of
>   memory, two IntelXeon X5570 quad-core CPUs, and two NVIDIA Tesla M2050
>   GPUs, running Ubuntu 12.04.
>
> (16) Somoclu: An Efficient Parallel Library for Self-Organizing Maps, Available from:
>   https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236635216_Somoclu_An_Efficient_Parallel_Library_for_Self-Organizing_Maps

It seems that both your CPU and your GPU are more powerful than the AWS benchmark.

Comment: I ran that same simulation on my PC, and got the same results as in the question (CPU outperformed GPU). The only thing that may have not be the same was the number of iterations, as it wasn't stated in the paper as far as I noticed. But the mapsize and the input data dimensions were the same (50x50 and 1000, respectively).